# How do I fix "error loading documents " Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've logged in into firebase and I can not see my Firestore database . Anyone had a similar issue or how can I fix it ? On the phone I have the same issue..

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by switching to Google Chrome from Safari